# Citations in Beamer that don't line feed

Tags: beamer, bibtex

This is what I wrote in **example1.tex**:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{newcent}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}{}
\begin{document}
\frame{\frametitle{Part One}
An example sentence that is citing this reference~\cite{wmo11} and this reference~\cite{noaa14}.}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{biblio1}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And this is what I wrote in **biblio1.bib**:

```
@Book{wmo11,
author = "{World Meteorological Organization}",
title = "Manual on the Global Observation System: Volume 2--Regional Aspects",
year = "2011",
publisher = "World Meteorological Organization"
}

@Misc{noaa14,
author = "{National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration}",
title = "{I}ntegrated {S}urface {D}atabase ({ISD})",
year = "2014",
howpublished="Retrieved October 10, 2014, from \url{http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/land-based-station-data/land-based-datasets/integrated-surface-database-isd}"
}
```

And this is the output I got:

[image: my output]

I wish to get an output like this:

[image: the output I need]

What changes should I make?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `\cite` puts the citation text in a box, so it makes an unbreakable unit. In your case you just want to remove this boxing which is provided by the internal command `\@cite@ofmt`, so we redefine this one to simply deliver its argument.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{wmo11,
author = "{World Meteorological Organization}",
title = "Manual on the Global Observation System: Volume 2--Regional Aspects",
year = "2011",
publisher = "World Meteorological Organization"
}

@Misc{noaa14,
author = "{National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration}",
title = "{I}ntegrated {S}urface {D}atabase ({ISD})",
year = "2014",
howpublished="Retrieved October 10, 2014, from \url{http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/land-based-station-data/land-based-datasets/integrated-surface-database-isd}"
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{newcent}

\makeatletter
\let\@cite@ofmt\@firstofone % not \hbox
\makeatother

\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Part One}

An example sentence that is citing this reference \cite{wmo11}
and this reference \cite{noaa14}.
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I used the `filecontents*` environment just to make the example self contained, use your own file as in the example you gave.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how to fix it in a simple way with bibtex.

In my opinion, the simplest solution is to use Biblatex and biber instead of bibtex. There are so much more powerful and they don't have this problem.

MWE (You need to have biblatex and biber installed):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio1.bib}
\usepackage{newcent}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry title}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry location}{}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography entry note}{}
\begin{document}
\frame{\frametitle{Part One}
An example sentence that is citing this reference~\parencite{wmo11} and this reference~\parencite{noaa14}.}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
\frametitle{References}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tried this but can't make it work. I get the error "Package biblatex Error: File 'example1.bbl' not created by biblatex."

Comment: @qzx You probably need to clean your files and restart just with the .tex and .bib.

Comment: yes, I tried deleting all the files except the .tex and .bib and it compiled without error but what is displayed no longer contains the author's names (i.e., "An example sentence that is citing this reference (wmo11) and this reference (noaa14)."). It's as if it can't find the .bib file when they are in the same directory.

Comment: You need to compile several times with biber+latex in order to get the citations generated. Try something like latex+biber+biber+latex+latex. Latex uses the files generated by previous compilations. You should have a error/warning message if you need to launch biber or latex one more time.

Comment: I tried again running biber and latex several times and I get the following error message:

INFO - This is Biber 1.9
INFO - Logfile is 'example1.blg'
read_file 'C:\directory\recode_data.xml' - sysopen: No such file or directory at C:\directory\bda77484.pm line 112.

Comment: And the .bbl file was not created. Is there something wrong with my .bcf file?

Comment: It finally worked... after I rebooted my laptop and re-installed the babel-english package. I just did a latex+biber+latex run. Thanks.